# Directive binding with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a custom directive in AngularJS. 
In the link function I'm adding the ng-model and ng-options attributes to the inner template, but, unfortunately the binding doesn't work. 
But when I place the inner template as is into my html file all works well.

```
application.directive("customSelect", function () {
var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<select name="ArrDeplocation" class="arrdepSelect"></select>',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
        console.log('scope: ', scope);
        console.log('element: ', elem);
        console.log('attribute: ', attr);

        $(elem.children()[0]).attr('ng-model', 'model.selectedCity');
        $(elem.children()[0]).attr('ng-options', 'city for city in model.cities');

        $(elem.children()[0]).selectmenu();

    }
};
return directive;
});
```

Comment: Tried, it throws and exception, saying $apply is in process

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you need to set attributes in the link func.
You can simply put into your template.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9u6nkLYKHxBBiJ60mpbF?p=preview

```
app.directive("customSelect", function () {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<select name="ArrDeplocation" class="arrdepSelect"'
     + 'ng-model="model.selectedCity" ng-options="city for city in model.cities">    </select>',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
      // run jquery mobile methods here...
    }
  };
  return directive;
});
```

You may want to elaborate what you really want to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify your template in the link function, then you must *recompile* it.

**Solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/bpiqXdQe91RJBaJXTPXO?p=preview**

```
app.directive("customSelect", function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<select name="ArrDeplocation" class="arrdepSelect"></select>',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
      elem.find('select').attr({
        'ng-model':   'model.selectedCity',
        'ng-options': 'city for city in model.cities'
      });
      var tpl = elem.html();
      elem.html($compile(tpl)(scope));
      elem.find('select').selectmenu();
    }
  };
});
```

The `$compile("html string")` compiles the template into:

> a link function which is used to bind template (a DOM element/tree) to a scope